# simple Jquery variable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to concatenate my `div` to images within it using `jquery` variable. Not sure how to do this. Thanks for any helps.

```
var pictureDiv = $('#pictureDiv');

pictureDiv.css('height','500');

//I want to change image within my pictureDiv and 
//want to use my pictureDiv variable..
pictureDiv.img??

//I also want to change p tag within my pictureDiv and
// want to use my pictureDiv variable..
pictureDiv.p??
```

Comment: You're looking for `.find()`, as in `pictureDiv.find('img')` or whatever.

Comment: Use the .find() method for everything inside an element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the picture div has `<p>` tags in it, is it the actual image or a container that contains both `<p>` tags and `<img>` tags? If it's a container, use the `.find()` function like this:

```
pictureDiv.find('img').attr('src',SomeValue);
pictureDiv.find('p')....
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have p tag and img tag in pictureDiv

```
var pictureDiv = $('#pictureDiv');

pictureDiv.css('height','500');

$("img",pictureDiv).attr("src","image path");

$("p",pictureDiv).html("insert text into p tag");
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery('#pictureDiv').find("img");
jQuery('#pictureDiv').find("p");

This should get you the list of images.

That is if I understood the question correctly.

hth